# VBA open files, edit, save

Tags: vba, automation, save, editing

I am trying to find a code which solves the following problem:

- open a couple of csv files in one folder
- run a formatting
- save it as a xlsx file

The code for the formatting I have already in place. I just do not know how to open all files automatically, do the formatting and save them.

Looking forward to your answers.
Best

Comment: I am not promoting to use it all the time, but I think the macro record function may come in handy for this case. And although you said you have code for formatting, stackoverflow users are not likely to perform complete coding service. A bit of your own effort towards it will help you learn it and additionally raise your chances to get help here.

Answer (score 0):

To open a file, you can modify this code(location & file name with extension):

```
patH = "C:\General\"
filE = "Example.csv"  
Workbooks.Open Filename:=patH & filE
```

To save the formatted file, you can modify this code below(will overwrite if a file with same name exists):

```
path2 = "C:\General\"
file2 = "Example2"
dirFile = path2 & file2
ThisWorkBook.SaveAs dirFile, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, _
    ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
```